# Removing certain row from datatable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to remove rows from datatable in which a certain cell is empty. I have tried using for loop but to no avail.

```
for (int i = dtbl.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
           DataRow dr = dtbl.Rows[i];
            if (dr["id"] == null)
               dtbl.Rows.Remove(dr);
        }
```

[image]

If the cell of ID column is empty, then that row should be deleted.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to compare to `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`?

Comment: Do you ever have empty strings in it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your test to this one.

```
for (int i = dtbl.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = dtbl.Rows[i];
    if (dr.IsNull("id"))
        dtbl.Rows.Remove(dr);
}
```

See docs: [DataRow.IsNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=net-5.0)

or you can use a check against the special field [DbValue.Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=net-5.0)

```
if (dr["id"] == DbNull.Value)
```

Another approach is this one

```
for (int i = dtbl.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = dtbl.Rows[i];
    if (dr.IsNull("id"))
        dr.Delete();
}
dtbl.AcceptChanges();
```

this last one just marks the row for deletion, but the row remains in the table until you call AcceptChanges. (So this approach is suitable for a  *foreach* loop)
Calling DataRow.Delete is the preferred way to work if you plan to update the real database table at later time (for example when you want your user delete many rows from a bound grid and then make a single update to the database only if the user clicks on a Save button).

Answer (score 1):

You could use linq to select those not null

```
   dtbl = dtbl.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => r.Field<string>("id") != null)
         .CopyToDataTable();
```

Might need the type, specify that nullable type to compare `row.Field<int?>("id").HasValue`

Comment: Linq is very useful but sometimes you should resist to its magic. Here for example, it will crash if the resulting enumeration doesn't contain any row, also, this code will create another datatable in memory and if the source datatable is very big you could face memory problems.

Comment: @Steve  Agree; which technology feature to use is one of the things we as developers must determine and decide upon within any given context.  I work on data that has many billions of rows in an individual table and there are hundreds of tables in a given scope (database/schema) and many databases for example and this would not be a suggested use in that context example.